# Does Fragments with setRetainInstance(true) survive process shutdowns?

Tags: android, process, fragment, lifecycle, retain

Considering this scenario: If I created an activity and it moves to the background and this activity contains a `Fragment` which is set to `setRetainInstance(true)` then the Android OS might at some point still decide to shut down the activity's hosting process in order to free memory.

Then the `Activity`'s state is saved via `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` where - as far as I understood - the related `Bundle` is written and to the file system to survive the process shut down. (thus the requirement of objects in the bundle being `Serializable`). Later, the applications state can be retrieved in a new process via `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`.

In contrast, my `Fragment` is allowed to contain variables which are not necessarily `Serializable`. Therefore, I figured, the `Fragment` cannot be stored on disk like the `Bundle` is. So what happens to my fragment when the process gets killed?

I was wondering about this reading the developer's guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):

> A process holding an activity that's not currently visible to the user
>   (the activity's onStop() method has been called). These processes have
>   no direct impact on the user experience, and **the system can kill them
>   at any time to reclaim memory** for a foreground, visible, or service
>   process. Usually there are many background processes running, so they
>   are kept in an LRU (least recently used) list to ensure that the
>   process with the activity that was most recently seen by the user is
>   the last to be killed. **If an activity implements its lifecycle methods
>   correctly, and saves its current state**, killing its process will not
>   have a visible effect on the user experience, because when the user
>   navigates back to the activity, the activity restores all of its
>   visible state.

I understood the above *killing* such that the VM instance is shut down and the state of the process is written to the file system (here comes the `Bundle` into play). Later the bundles are read for resuming the process. Since the retaining of fragments is not concerned with life cycle methods and since I would not know how to retain e.g. a pointer to a network connection (you should of course never have such a pointer in a fragment anyhow), I was wondering if the fragments are still restored if the process is shut down in the meantime. I concluded that they surely needed to be recreated and that the life cycle methods are therefore to be preferred over `setRetainInstance(true)` whenever possible.

Does this assumption make any sense?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like you're mixing up two concepts here.

- Saving state across Configuration Changes does not involve serialization. If you request `setRetainInstance()` for a `Fragment` then that means it will fully stay in memory and not be re-created *only* for configuration changes. A similar mechanism is available for `Activity` objects but they need to explicitly define an `Object` which is going to be saved. This works via `Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, *not* via `onSaveInstanceStae()`.
- The other mechanism involves serialization and possibly (maybe not always, not sure) file system I/O to be able to reproduce state information even if an `Activity`/`Fragment` is destroyed (which happens independently of its hosting `Process`, btw). This works via `Activity.onSaveInstanceState()` and `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState()`.
- Of course, you can use the second mechanism for the purpose of the first, thus slowing down the way your app deals with configuration changes. Depending on your internal state, the slowdown could me marginal of significant.

Regarding your questions.

- "My Fragment in contrast, is allowed to contain variables which are not serializable." Well, the same is true for your `Activity`. It can contain non-serializable objects which can be saved across config changes as described above.
- "the fragment cannot be stored to disk when a process is shut down and must be recreated when an activity was restored." No, both mechanisms are available for both object types.

Hope I could contribute to clarifying this a bit.

**Edit** after your first comment.

Regarding the comment:

- "`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` is deprecated": Yes. I mentioned it for demonstration purposes because of a specific wording in your question. Also, with Android 2 devices having a 46% market share as per today (official Google figures), this method will definitely stay around for a *very* long time, deprecated or not.
- "My main concern is about what will happen to the fragment instance when my hosting process is killed and removed from the memory": Your fragment *instance* will be removed from memory and there's of course no way it is restored as-is with its *complete* internal state *automatically*. This is *only* done when you `setRetainInstanceState` in the case of config changes. (But note that this relates to the *Instance*, in other words, the full object.)

Regarding your edit:

- Once more, *yes*, your `Fragment`'s `Bundle` *will* be stored and restored to/from the `Bundle` *regardless* of `setRetainInstanceState` if you use `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState()` for this purpose, for everything that makes sense.
- It is *not* true that "all of its visible state" will be saved as the text you refer to claims; for example, the `visibility` attribute will *not* be saved. Whether that's supposed to be a bug or a feature I don't know, but it's a *fact*. But this is only a side remark; UI elements *will* save most of their relevant state.
- "the state of the process is written to the file system": No! The state of *objects* which are able to save their state to a `Bundle` and actually *implement* saving their state will be saved in a `Bundle`, this means that you must provide such information yourself if you want your `Fragment` to save some state information. Also, again: *No*, this does not only relate to killing the process but also to deleting `Activity` and `Fragment` objects which are not visible; like the last Activity shown -- the `Process` may well stay alive.
- "bundles are read for resuming the process": No, the `Bundle` will be read to *pass it to the re-construction of Activity and/or Fragment objects*, there is *nothing* done automatically in this process (except library objects which save their state also restore their state), but *Android* does *not* "resume" the "Process" from these `Bundle`s.
- "Since the retaining of fragments is not concerned with life cycle methods": Again, I think you're mixing up the two concepts. The "retaining" of a `Fragment` is *only* performed upon *configuration changes* _IF_ you request it via `setRetainInstance`, but we're mostly talking about the re-creation of `Fragment` objects from a `Bundle` here, which *does* involve the life cycle methods as documented by Google.
- "I would not know how to retain e.g. a pointer to a network connection": Again, this must be a statement based on your mix-up. Of course you can keep a reference to a network connection *upon config change* (as requested per `setRetainInstance`) because when that happens, everything is simply kept in memory. Also, even if your `Fragment` gets deleted (because it became invisible) and your process is still there (because it shows the next Activity), you can (and should) keep references to objects which are expensive to re-create, such as a network connection, in your `Application` object, which exists as long as your process lives (more or less). It is *only* when your whole *app* is killed by Android that you lose everything, but the serialization we're discussing *happens much more often*.

Your conclusion:

> I concluded that they surely needed to be recreated and that the life cycle methods are therefore to be preferred over setRetainInstance(true) whenever possible. Does this assumption make any sense?

Unfortunately not, since you are mixing up completely independent concepts.

I'll give it a final try:

- You will want to keep a *network connection* reference which you need throughout your app in your `Application` object because it would be a lousy user experience if you created it from scratch on a regular basis throughout your app.
- Your `Application` object will only die if Android kills your app.
- Your `Activity` and `Fragment` objects will be deleted from your app regularly when the user moves forward within your app.
- When the user presses "back", Android will re-create `Activity` and `Fragment` objects from `Bundle`s using lifecycle methods. Saving something in a Bundle makes sense if you have expensive computations to do to re-create the internal state. You can live without the `Bundle` mechanism because Android will always save the `Intent` so if you don't do anything then you'll start without saved state.
- When a configuration change occurs, Android lets you optimize user experience by keeping objects in memory across the config change. Here, `Activity` life cycle methods get involvwed and it's up to your implementation to use the saved data effectively. For `Fragment`s, this is where `setRetainInstance' comes into play: Your`Fragment` will survive the config change in memory if you set it.

Comment: I edited my question to further clarify it. My main concern is about what will happen to the fragment instance when my hosting process is killed and removed from the memory.

Btw: `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed answer. This makes a lot of more sense now.

Comment: I might just add: That is actually how I thought it worked in the beginning, but the javadoc entry to `setRetainInstance` saying **Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change)** got me confused since it simply speaks of _re-creation_. I read this as if this would affect any re-creation of a fragment. The entry to `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` is much clearer. Not to speak of your explanation above. So thank you again!

Comment: @raphw Glad you found my text readable. Android docs can be confusing (sometimes even misleading). If I hadn't learned this from a book, I think I'd have spent hours trying to understand it...

Comment: You don't happen to remember this book's title?

Comment: @raphw One of the best Android books I know, [Android in Practice](http://www.manning.com/collins/), section 3.3.2.